# Create a distinct list of a part of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` called 'stockData'.  Below is the head of a very small example that contains all of the different types of column name.

```
            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_RAWLAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_RAWVOLUME  \
date                                                           
2008-02-04                  262.00                  23397414   
2008-02-05                  257.25                  35213970   
2008-02-06                  262.75                  41323308   
2008-02-07                  237.00                 123276113   
2008-02-08                  231.00                  76456078   

            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_RAWVWAP  \
date                                                        
2008-02-04             20875.7353                263.4303   
2008-02-05             20497.5582                261.6408   
2008-02-06             20935.7956                262.3705   
2008-02-07             18884.0477                241.9444   
2008-02-08             18389.9269                234.4538   

            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_RAWCLOSE  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST_ADJ  \
date                                                           
2008-02-04                   262.00                   262.00   
2008-02-05                   257.25                   257.25   
2008-02-06                   262.75                   262.75   
2008-02-07                   237.00                   237.00   
2008-02-08                   231.00                   231.00   

            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VWAP_ADJ  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME_ADJ  \
date                                                             
2008-02-04                 263.4303                   23397414   
2008-02-05                 261.6408                   35213970   
2008-02-06                 262.3705                   41323308   
2008-02-07                 241.9444                  123276113   
2008-02-08                 234.4538                   76456078   

            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_CLOSE_ADJ  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_RAWLAST  \
date                                                           
2008-02-04                    262.00                   177.9   
2008-02-05                    257.25                   173.6   
2008-02-06                    262.75                   174.2   
2008-02-07                    237.00                   170.0   
2008-02-08                    231.00                   174.3   

              BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME_ADJ  \
date                    ...                                           
2008-02-04              ...                               114868730   
2008-02-05              ...                               165372960   
2008-02-06              ...                               154129543   
2008-02-07              ...                               187932809   
2008-02-08              ...                               160997280   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_CLOSE_ADJ  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_EXCHANGE_HOLIDAY  \
date                                                                    
2008-02-04                     177.9                              NaN   
2008-02-05                     173.6                              NaN   
2008-02-06                     174.2                              NaN   
2008-02-07                     170.0                              NaN   
2008-02-08                     174.3                              NaN   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_CORP_ACTION  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_REPORTING  \
date                                                               
2008-02-04                         NaN                       NaN   
2008-02-05                         NaN                       NaN   
2008-02-06                         NaN                       NaN   
2008-02-07                         NaN                       NaN   
2008-02-08                         NaN                       NaN   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_FX  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST_ADJ_EUR  \
date                                                         
2008-02-04             1.3307                    236.73153   
2008-02-05             1.3411                    232.81496   
2008-02-06             1.3406                    233.53252   
2008-02-07             1.3410                    227.97000   
2008-02-08             1.3415                    233.82345   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP_EUR  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VWAP_ADJ_EUR  \
date                                                                 
2008-02-04              125761.886753                   237.215373   
2008-02-05              123681.237732                   235.310211   
2008-02-06              124062.436220                   233.089586   
2008-02-07              121107.388396                   229.125137   
2008-02-08              124216.990692                   233.210250   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_CLOSE_ADJ_EUR  
date                                      
2008-02-04                     236.73153  
2008-02-05                     232.81496  
2008-02-06                     233.53252  
2008-02-07                     227.97000  
2008-02-08                     233.82345
```

The column headers are made up of 2 sections 
part one - company name (for example BBG.XLON.BTA.S)
part two - a description of the data in the column (for example RAWCLOSE)

I am would like to get a distinct list of all of the column names (all of the part ones).  As you can see from the data frame each company has more that one column of data and there is potentially hundreds of companies.

So in this example where there are only two stocks I would like returned a dataframe that looks like:

```
id
BBG.XLON.BTA.S
BBG.XLON.VOD.S
```

But I have no idea how I would do this. I think I might have to split the column names and then some how write a distinct list of each part one element but need help as to how to perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `list` comprehension over the `column` names using `df.columns`, use `.split('_')` and keep only the first part to get the stock name, then use `np.unique()` to remove duplicates and convert to `pd.Series`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(np.unique([col.split('_')[0] for col in df.columns]), name='id')
```

See [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) for `np.unique`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas' `Series.str.extract` and a regular expression as follows:

```
s = pd.Series(df.columns)  # assuming your DataFrame is `df`

s.str.extract('^([^_]+)', expand=False).unique()

# returns
# array(['BBG.XLON.BTA.S', 'BBG.XLON.VOD.S'], dtype=object)
```

then you can send this to `pd.Series( , name='id')`